# How to practically measure an input impedance?

Tags: input-impedance

I would like to know how I could practically measure the input impedance of the following circuit:

[image]

---

I update my post by adding the rest of the circuit.

[image]

This is what my circuit looks like. The aim of my test is to measure a differential input impedance 10 kohms ±10% in the bandwidth (300-2000 Hz).

I hope that is clear enough for you so that you could help me.

Comment: Welcome! At DC? Multimeter.

Comment: Is this the sole circuit ? is the output impedance large compared to the rest of the component values ?

Comment: @winny , at AC not DC.  It is actually an input impedance of an audio channel including an anti-aliaising filter. I have to make sure that the input impedance (represented by the three resistances in the previous picture)  of the audio channel is a 10Kohms.

Comment: Thanks. Where are the DSP_TEST_ANA_* points connected?

Comment: @Y.OU - Hi, On Stack Exchange the procedure is for someone who asks a question (the "OP") to edit the question to add any new information. The only time that an OP would write an answer below is if they have solved the problem themselves, no more help is needed, and the question can be closed. Therefore I moved your extra info from an "answer" to become an update in the question. Please see the [tour] and the [help] for more rules and etiquette details. Thanks.

Comment: @devnull, DSP_TEST_ANA is a signal generated by the CPU (PWM output pin)  and transformed into differential signal using the dual OP-AMP ADA4940 then injected in audio channels to perform an audio test. I think this signal has no effect on the input impedance that i want to measure?!

Comment: @SamGibson, thanks for these clarifications, i will check the rules and the etiquette details  as recommended

Comment: Ah! That wasn't clear in your original question. What do you have access to? Signal generator and oscilloscope?

Comment: @winny , yees i have access to both signal generator and oscilloscope.

Comment: Then suitable resistor in series with your signal generator, measure the voltage on the input to your circuit and the voltage drop across your resistor.

Comment: @winny, i don't understand what do you mean by suitable resistance ? should it be a variable resistance? and i didn't get the test procedure, could you explain more please ?

Comment: First hit on Google: http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Theory/inzoz.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to measure an input impedance is to drive the input with a signal, in series with two different known impedances, and measure the change in output level when changing drive impedance.

The most convenient impedances to use are zero, and one in the ballpark of your expected input impedance. If the output halves when going to the second impedance, then your external impedance is equal to your internal one. Otherwise you just have to write and solve the equation for voltage division into the input with arbitrary impedances.

Comment: I don't understand why exactly two different known impedances?! when making some researches, i have seen methods using one variable resistor . What is the difference between this method and yours?

Comment: @Y.OU One variable resistor is a way of switching between two different known impedances with one component. I'll bet the method said 'turn the resistor down to zero, measure output, increase resistor until output halves, remove resistor and measure it'. Am I right? Alternatively if you know the gain accurately, you can do it in one further measurement (knowin the gain accurately substitutes for the first reference measurement)

Comment: Yes you're right. Which gain you mean ?

Comment: @Y.OU the gain of the amplifier from the input to the output, so you don't need to measure the reference output.  (knowin the gain accurately substitutes for the first reference measurement)